# Open my application from another in android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

My boss asked me to prove that my application behaves properly when summoned by another application (dunno why he asked that).

So I have two apps here, one launches a second one. How I launch the specific app I want? Using Intent launch seemly any generic app that reaches a certain goal, not the app I really want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a try.

```
Intent secondIntent = new Intent();
secondIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
secondIntent.setClassName("com.example", "com.example.YourSecondApp");
startActivity(secondIntent);
```

I should point out that `com.example` should be the package of your second application (the one you want to call) and `com.example.YourSecondapp` is the class name where you have your onCreate() method.

Comment: Would be nice to check what of YOUR apps are installed.. good for advertisements

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent secondApp = new Intent("com.test.SecondApp");
startActivity(secondApp);
```

Check out for more examples
http://developer.android.com/resources/faq/commontasks.html#opennewscreen

Answer (score 0):

Create one Intent using the following code

### Explicit Intent

When you know the particular component(`activity/service`) to be loaded

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClass("className/package name");

start<Activity/Service>(intent);
```

### Imlicit Intent

When we do not have the idea which class to load and we know the Action to be perform by the launched application we can go with this intent.

Action needs to set, and the Android run time fallows the `intent Resolution technique` and list out(one or more components) the components to perform the action. from the list out components (if more than one), user will get the chance to launch his chosen application